# forward LIBOR curve bootstrapping

Tags: interest-rate-swap, libor, ois, multicurve, forward-curve

how can i construct a forward libor curve, which produces forward LIBOR rates, with the given data/info:

- par rates of a set of OIS
- fixed 6M LIBOR rate
- par rates of a set of Swaps which the underlying is 6M-LIBOR and floating leg pays semi-annually whiled fixed leg pays annually

I am asking your guidance on how to build a forward LIBOR curve under multi-curve approach.

Comment: There are plenty of resources online and on QSE incl. the Ametrano paper amongst others https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2219548